# How can i add attribute to an object in Lua?

Tags: object, lua

I am trying to add an attirubute to objects that i created.Here i created bird display objects but i want to add those birds a spesific attiribute like typeOfBird and then i want to reach those attiributes like bird.typeOfBird . How can i do that?

```
 module(...,package.seeall)

  function new(params)
  local bird=display.newImage(params.img,params.x,params.y)

  function bird:touch(event)
local t = event.target
local phase = event.phase

if "began" == phase then
    -- Make target the top-most object
    local parent = t.parent
    parent:insert( t )
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )

    t.isFocus = true
elseif t.isFocus then
    if "moved" == phase then
        t.x = event.x
        t.y = event.y 
    elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        t.isFocus = false
    end
   end

 return true
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like bird objects are already simple lua tables,
so you can just get and set the values as normal. So for example you could add lines like:

```
if self.typeOfBird == "gull" then ... end
```

and

```
self.typeOfBird = "parrot"
```

to your `bird:touch` function.

Or

```
bird.typeOfBird = "gull"
```

in your `new` function.